# Gitlab: remote: Your SSH key has expired

Tags: gitlab

I was trying to push changes to the branch but i got this error:

```
remote: Your SSH key has expired.
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

i generated new access token in gitlab settings but i'm not sure how can i add to my project so i can push again

Comment: Why did you generate a new access token when you need a new ssh key?

Comment: Access tokens and SSH keys are two separate access mechanisms: the former is used for HTTP access, the latter for SSH access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SSH-key is not your access-key.

Go to settings and setup a new SSH-key.

### Edit

1. Click on "Preferences"
   [image: Image for opening settings dialoge]
2. Click on "SSH Keys" (it is under "Access token")
   [image: Image of settings]
3. Just add a key (fill out "Key" and "Title" and press "Add key" button
   [image: SSH Dialog]

Comment: sorry, but where can i find an option to setup a new ssh-key. I only could find the option to generate the access tokens

Comment: is there a way to make public key private ?

Comment: A public key private? What do you mean?

Comment: check https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html

Answer (score 10):

This is a hack but if you're using that ssh key elsewhere to and don't want to update it everywhere AND you don't have security concerns, you can scroll all the way down on the page where gitlab displays your expired ssh key and hit Remove. Then you can add the same key again and have 1 more year validity on it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Follow the documentation to generate a new SSH key and remove your old one / add the new one:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html

Comment: Waw, it works's, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to [Profile->SSH Keys](https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys) , remove the key that expired and then re-add it.

Although not recommended, you can avoid that a SSH Key expires by removing the expire date on creation. By default, expire date is set to next year. If you click the cancel icon, expiration date is set to *never*:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else lands on this question looking for clues on why their new key does not work after configuring your SSH client to use it:

For me, I had to remove the expired key from GitLab (and potentially your client) to make it proceed with trying the new one.